# Why does `devtools::document()` trip on `setMethod` whose function definition is empty?

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

Assume I am building an R package with `devtools` in RStudio.

Assume also I have this R source file with the following code:

```r
#' @param object An object
#' @param data Numeric vector or data.frame
#' @param Fun Function. Default function is \code{sum}
#' @param ... Extra named arguments passed to FUN
#' @rdname myGeneric
#' @export
setGeneric("myGeneric", function(object, data, FUN, ...)
{standardGeneric ("myGeneric")} )

#' @rdname myGeneric
setMethod("myGeneric", c("numeric", "numeric", "function"),
          function(object, data, FUN, ...) {
            return(42)
            }
          )
```

Now, `devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))` runs fine except for that warning about the missing *name/title*:

```
> devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))
Updating gwasrapidd documentation
Loading gwasrapidd
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing NAMESPACE
Warning message:
myGeneric.Rd is missing name/title. Skipping
```

However if I comment that line `return(42)` inside the function definition like so:

```r
#' @param object An object
#' @param data Numeric vector or data.frame
#' @param Fun Function. Default function is \code{sum}
#' @param ... Extra named arguments passed to FUN
#' @rdname myGeneric
#' @export
setGeneric("myGeneric", function(object, data, FUN, ...)
{standardGeneric ("myGeneric")} )

#' @rdname myGeneric
setMethod("myGeneric", c("numeric", "numeric", "function"),
          function(object, data, FUN, ...) {
            #return(42)
            }
          )
```

and run again `devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))` I get now an error:

```
> devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))
Updating gwasrapidd documentation
Loading gwasrapidd
Error in method_body[[2]] : subscript out of bounds
```

My question is why? Is it a bug of `devtools`?

Package versions:

- devtools_1.13.6
- roxygen2_6.1.1

Comment: It sounds like a more appropriate place to report this error would be the devtools github issues page: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues assuming the issue is that you want devtools to gracefully support empty generic functions (?)

Comment: Well I don't necessarily want/need `devtools` to support empty generic (actually methods) functions :D I am just trying to be sure the problem is not on my side. I don't mind it being a devtools bug for such special condition. I just want to know.

Comment: @MrFlick: meanwhile I did report this error as a github issue: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1984 (how Orwellian...)

Comment: And here: https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/843.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a bug in `roxygen`: https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/843